# Dynamically Created DataGridView With Seperate DataSources (Same Name)

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

I have an app that has Tabs, I dynamically add controls to the relevant tab based on the number of ID's I return from a web service.

I have created a sub that I pass the ID to and this then creates all the controls for the 'next' ID's details.

In this I have datagridviews, I create the datagridviews fine but when I bind the datasource it has exactly the same information on the datagridview on BOTH tabs even though I have it declared separately.

Could someone shed some light on this for me please. The code below works the first time, but the second time this loops the information is exactly the same across each created tab.

I have used a code converter to open up the possibly of answers from a wider audience rather than just vb.net which I'm comfortable with, I can backwards engineer a c# soluiton I feel.

VB.NET

```
Dim NewDGV As New DataGridView
NewDGV.Name = "Restrictions" & DriverNo
NewDGV.Location = New Point(1, 1)
NewDGV.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

Dim dtRestrictions As New DataTable
dtRestrictions = Results.RestrictionsTbl
dtRestrictions.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Driver = " & DriverNo & ""
NewDGV.DataSource = dtRestrictions

NewGrpBx.Controls.Add(NewDGV)
```

C#

```
DataGridView NewDGV = new DataGridView();
NewDGV.Name = "Restrictions" + DriverNo;
NewDGV.Location = new Point(1, 1);
NewDGV.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

DataTable dtRestrictions = new DataTable();
dtRestrictions = Results.RestrictionsTbl;
dtRestrictions.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Driver = " + DriverNo + "";
NewDGV.DataSource = dtRestrictions;

NewGrpBx.Controls.Add(NewDGV);
```